# How to gracefully end a Quartz 3.0.x with ASP.NET Core 2.2 job in IIS?

Tags: quartz.net, shutdown, iis-10, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to gracefully end a Quartz job which run in IIS. My code is as follows:

#### the job

```
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class TestJob : IJob
    {
        private ILoggingService Logger { get; }
        private IApplicationLifetime ApplicationLifetime { get; }

        private static object lockHandle = new object();
        private static bool shouldExit = false;

        public TestJob(ILoggingService loggingService, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            Logger = loggingService;
            ApplicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
        }

        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            //TODO: does not seem work
            //context.CancellationToken.Register(() =>
            //{
            //    lock (lockHandle)
            //    {
            //        shouldExit = true;
            //    }
            //});

            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //TODO: check
                ApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
                {
                    lock (lockHandle)
                    {
                        shouldExit = true;
                    }
                });

                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
                    {
                        lock (lockHandle)
                        {
                            if (shouldExit)
                            {
                                Logger.LogDebug($"TestJob detected that application is shutting down - exiting");
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        Logger.LogDebug($"TestJob ran step {i+1}");
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Logger.LogError(exc, "An error occurred during execution of scheduled job");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

#### Startup.cs

```
protected void StartJobs(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    var scheduler = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IScheduler>();
    //TODO: use some config
    QuartzServicesUtilities.StartJob<TestJob>(scheduler, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

    lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => scheduler.Start());
    lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => scheduler.Shutdown());
}

private static void ConfigureApplicationLifetime(ILoggingService logger, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
    {
        logger.LogInfo(null, "Application is stopping...");
    });

    lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
    {
        logger.LogInfo(null, "Application stopped");
    });
}
```

So, I have hooked to `ApplicationStopping` to be able to shutdown Quartz jobs in a graceful way. However, when IIS application pool is about to be ended the jobs are ended abruptly:

- change something in web.config to trigger application pool stopping
- application pool is configured to allow up to 90s before ending. Also overlapping is allowed
- logging records `Application is stopping` and immediately `Application stopped`, thus the job is finished abruptly

I remember that a similar implementation worked in ASP.NET with Quartz 2.x: Quartz jobs were allowed to finalise their work provided they managed to do so within application pool shutdown period.

**Question:** How to gracefully end a Quartz 3.0.x with ASP.NET Core 2.2 job in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a `true` to 'scheduler.Shutdown()' to wait for the jobs to be finished. This should delay the pool shutdown till the jobs run to an end.

```
lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => scheduler.Shutdown(true));
```

You can read more about it [here](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/3.0/html/?topic=html/c0a37f4d-84df-9158-a4b0-b74f8db06c04.htm).

Comment: Can you please check the version of your Quartz? `IScheduler.Shutdown` signature does not fit your call: `Task Shutdown(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));`

Comment: To ensure that it is there, i created a .Net Core project and added Quartz 3.0.7 to it and the method is like in the documentation with the bool. Are you sure your IScheduler is the right interface from Quartz? The same works with an Asp.Net Core WebApplication. The is a `IScheduler` in Kestrel, maybe you mixed something up with it.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I somehow missed the overload. Thanks.